# Wait for task to finish before terminating in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I have a `Runnable` implementation that does some work which might take some time and  I am trying to schedule it using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`with `scheduleAtFixedRate` method. Now I want to ensure that shut down is graceful that means, Before terminating, task should be allowed to run completely. I have written following code for shutdown.

```
 public void shutDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        LOG.info("Gracefully shutting down executor");
        executor.shutdown();
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            // cancels currently executing tasks.
            LOG.info("Executor is still alive. Forcing executor thread pool to shut down");
            executor.shutdownNow();

            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                LOG.fatal("Executor thread pool did not terminate");
                throw new Exception("Unable to shut down executor thread pool forcefully");
            }
            LOG.info("Executor shut down.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception shutting down executor", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

But problem with this is, I have to specify time to wait explicitly and I can not predict time taken by task in advance. Is there a way to make executor wait indefinitely until executing task finishes without having to mention time to wait? Or is there a better way to work on above scenario?

Thanks

Jitendra

Comment: shutdown() should do graceful termination right? as per documentation, shutdown() Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Any reason why you have other code related to awaitTermination(...); Do you want to force shutdown, if it is not complete with in certain interval?

Comment: I think, it only initiates the shutdown and exits, does not block or wait until threads are shut down.

Comment: I want some kind of blocking call so that I know exactly when tasks have terminated

Comment: You can use a HUGE timeout period, like 10000 HOURS. I don't think your tasks need that much to finish. :)

Comment: yeah I can.. but I thought, there should be some good way for this :)

Comment: Well, basically you want an `awaitTermination(infinity)`. So, the closest you can get is `awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)`. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @Jitendra I've removed my answer.  It turns out there is no notification from the FutureTask's of a scheduled executor.  As a result the get will never return.  I think Tudor's answer is the best.  I was able to solve it with a Phaser though but that requires Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to "overprovision" so to speak. I suggest you use a huge timeout period that in no way can be exceeded by the time needed for a single task to execute, like:

```
// do you have tasks that can take more than 2^63 - 1 days to finish? :)
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shutdown()` to begin a graceful termination, and then use `awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)` to wait for the executor service to finish shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

As it was noted in the comment `executor.shutdown()` is not forcing any tasks to exit but rather it prevents new ones from being accepted. Have a look in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29).

Another advice is if you want to get hold of your tasks as soon as they complete, you can implement [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of a `Runnable` that it's of a generic type and returns a value of type T. Then you can wrap this [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) into a [`FutureTask<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and submit that to your `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. You can then loop through your tasks as soon as they have completed their work and are available. So in short something like this (notice as soon as we are done loading the scheduler with tasks it's safe to shut it down meaning that we don't allow any further tasks to be submitted from then on):

```
ScheduledExecutorService schedulerExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(n);
Callable<Integer> myTask = . . .;
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(myTask);
schedulerExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
schedulerExecutor.shutdown();
```